# Use induction to prove the inequilities

Tags: induction

Use mathematical induction to prove:
$$\frac{n}{2} < \sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{k} < n$$
To prove the left part.
Assume:
$$\frac{m}{2} < \sum_{k=1}^{2^m-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
Want to prove:
$$\frac{m+1}{2} < \sum_{k=1}^{2^{(m+1)}-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
I have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{(m+1)}-1}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{m}-1}\frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=2^m}^{2*2^{m}-1}\frac{1}{k} > \frac{m}{2} + \sum_{k=2^m}^{2*2^{m}-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
It is enough to prove:
$$\frac{m}{2} + \sum_{k=2^m}^{2*2^{m}-1}\frac{1}{k} > \frac{m+1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} < \sum_{k=2^m}^{2*2^{m}-1}\frac{1}{k} $$
From here I don't know how to continue or maybe I was wrong from the beginning.
Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Each of the terms in the last sum is $>\frac1{2^{m1}}$

Comment: But in this case we get the last sum $ > \frac{1}{2^{m+1}} * (2^m - 1) = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$ and is smaller than $1/2$?

Comment: How many numbers are there from $2^m$ to $2^{m+1}-1$ inclusive?

Comment: Ohohoh sorry! $2^m$ it is.. I see the solution. Thank you!!